# ODI: SQL Server Source

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle-data-integrator

We need to extract a SQL Server source into ODI in our Oracle Database. 
In this source we have a difference between a NULL and an empty string. We need to capture this difference into ODI. Something like nvl(attribute, 'XXX') so that an empty string becomes a NULL into Oracle or something like that.

But in the physical mapping, coming from SQL Server, ODI always uses a temporary C$ table (which already is an Oracle table). After that C$ table, my 'nvl' gets applied but in Oracle a null and an empty string are handled the same.

Does anyone know how to handle this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the logical mapping you can apply to the target column the ANSI SQL function `coalesce(attribute, 'XXX')`, which is valid SQL Server syntax.

If you set the parameter `Execute on Hint: Source` the function will be applied to the SELECT statement on the Source before inserting into the C$ table.